# Golang GAE integration with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-sql

I'm having a lot of trouble connecting my Golang GAR to Google Cloud SQL. I'm currently using https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql driver. My connection string is

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "'root:password'@tcp(ip-address:3306)/dbname")
```

I always get 1045 error, according to Google:

> If MySQL rejects the connection, for example, because you have specified an incorrect MySQL user name or password, the error you receive will be:
>   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user-name'@'client-IP' (using password: YES)

When I connect to the db via SQL command line tool with the same username and password, I get access.

I doubled checked myself and went over all the SQL db creation steps including providing my IP address as authorized to connect the SQL db and creating user via MySQL command line.

There might be some problem with the string of the user name and pass that I'm providing to the Go SQL driver: "'root:password'@tcp(ip-address:3306)/dbname".

```
import (

    "time"
    "net/http"

    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/mysql"

    "appengine"
    "appengine/datastore"
    /*"appengine/user"*/

    "github.com/go-martini/martini"
    "github.com/codegangsta/martini-contrib/binding"

)

m.Get("/GetTheShop/:Bid" , func(params martini.Params,w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) string{

            db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "cloudsql:insName*db/user/pass")

            if err != nil {
                return(err.Error()+" 1") 
            }

            defer db.Close()
            // Open doesn't open a connection. Validate DSN data:

            err = db.Ping()
            if err != nil {
                return(err.Error()+" 2") 
            }

            return "db connected"
})
```

Comment: Have you read [Google's CloudSQL Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/cloud-sql/reference)? Are you importing the `cloudsql` package? Show some code.

Comment: Could you put all the code? By referring https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/cloud-sql/reference I'll try this db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "cloudsql:my-instance*dbname/user/passwd")

Comment: should i change the "mysql" in the connection string with the "cloudsql" and import the "appengin/cloudsql" ??
@tomwilde Thanks !

Comment: Did you try it? Did you get this working? Put some updates or self-answer the question.

Comment: I would highly recommend following the docs, as there are multiple different ways to connect. If using named instance method, is your instance actually named "insName" and your database name is really "db"?

Comment: no i didnt get this working .. im just using the datastore for now .. planning on getting this done later for keeping old data .. @anonymous4444